# Kotlin MPP - Cannot resolve Stetho Interceptor

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying out for the first time to build a Kotlin MPP using a Kotlin DSL gradle file.
The issue is quite simple but I've been trying everything I could think of to fix it : the android shared code can't resolve Stetho interceptor

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4aBZ.png)

My build.gradle.kts

```html
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

kotlin {
    //select iOS target platform depending on the Xcode environment variables
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "SharedCode"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("android")

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.3")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:0.14.0")

        // HTTP
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.3.0-rc")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:1.3.0-rc")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:1.3.0-rc")
    }

    sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.3.0-rc")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:1.3.0-rc")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:1.3.0-rc")
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:1.3.0-rc")
        implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.0.1")
        implementation( "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1")
    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

EDIT :

So I found out that when I replace

jvm("android")

with

android()

Stetho-interceptor can be imported, but the "expected" and "actual" keyword are not correctly linked by Android studio for iOS :

"Actual property ... has no corresponding expected declaration" when I hover an actual declaration for iOS

When I use both

jvm("android")
android()

I get a gradle error :

"The target 'android' already exists, but it was not created with the 'jvm' preset. To configure it, access it by name in `kotlin.targets` or use the preset function 'android'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to have jvm("android") if you already are using the android() target. if you want a separate jvm target then you should name it something different (ex. jvm("something") ).

Once you add your android target and manifest + android definitions, the libraries should resolve. the facebook library likely depends on an android target which is why it is not resolving.